# Classification of minimal connected topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected topological space with at least two points $a,b$. Connected meaning that the only clopen subsets of the space are the entire space and the empty set. Further assume $X$ has no connected proper subsets containing $a,b$. In this sense, $X$ is minimal. I'd like a classification of such topological spaces. In particular, I'd like to know what other possibilities there are other than $X$ simply being a line segment.

Thanks to Moishe Kohan for pointing me to the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc. This answers my question. In particular, this is what I was after: "In 2016 Logan Hoehn and Lex Oversteegen classified all planar homogeneous continua, up to a homeomorphism, as the circle, pseudo-arc and circle of pseudo-arcs."

Comment: And why do you think it is 'relatively clear'? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc

Comment: As far as I can tell $X$ could be a topologist's sine curve or something even wackier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve

Comment: @MoisheKohan, you're totally right, my claim is false. I changed the question apropriately. Also thanks for pointing me to the pseudo-arc page, this might be exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, The topologists sine doesn't have a limit point, so I'm not sure what b should be in this case, assuming a is the point (1/pi,0) for example. The topologists sine is not defined at x=0, and for any a with x value greater than 0, the result is just a line segment upto homeomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheKohan While it's clear to me that in the pseudoarc there are $a\neq b$ not belonging to any proper compact connected subspace, I think I'm missing something obvious, because I'm not seeing why there are $a\neq b $ not belonging to any proper connected subspace

Comment: @Mathew: I haven't checked this carefully but I think you can take $b$ to be the origin.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I think you're right, just add in the origin to the topologists sine curve and you've got a nice example. Thanks for this.